# Get fields from one class and set fields of another

Tags: java

I am fetching some info from a SOAP web-service, which gives me the output in the form of a particular POJO. At the same time, I have my own client POJO. I have to retrieve lots of fields from SOAP output and set those values into my class. For example:-

```
myClass.setVar1(soapOutput.getField1());
myClass.setVar2(soapOutput.getField2());
myClass.setVar3(soapOutput.getField3());
...
...
...

and so on
```

However, since the fields are huge in number, this results into that many number of statements, which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to reduce the number of lines of code to achieve this? One approach i can think of it is Reflection. Is there any other way?

-Thanks and Regards
Chinmay Phadke

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could consider using a `Collection` if you have dozens of fields for which it might make sense to group them.

Comment: You can use some external API for it like dozer.